# Canonical way of retrying in Flink operators

Tags: apache-flink

I have a couple of `Flink` jobs that receive data from a series of `Kafka` topics, do some aggregation, and publish the result into a `Kafka` topic.

The aggregation part is what gets somehow difficult. I have to retrieve some information from several HTTP endpoints and put together the responses in a particular format. Problem is that some of those outbound HTTP calls time out sometimes, so I need a way to retry them.

I was wondering if there is a canonical way to do such task within `Flink` operators, without doing something entirely manually. If not, what could be a recommended approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a bit more than a month you'll have Flink 1.16 available with retry support in AsyncIO:

- https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/asyncio/#retry-support

That is probably your best option. In the meantime, using AsyncIO, but configuring it to support long timeouts and handle the retries yourself in the `asyncInvoke` may be an option.

Comment: That's great! I'm yet to use the `RichAsyncFunction`, but I guess whenever I can upgrade to `1.16` that's going to be a must! Thanks!